# Show that the co-ordinates of the point on the join of $(-3, 7, -13)$ and $(-6, 1, -10)$ which is nearest to the intersection of the planes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d

> **Show that the co-ordinates of the point on the join of $(-3, 7, -13)$ and 
>   $(-6, 1, -10)$ which is nearest to the intersection of the planes $3x-y- 3z + 32 =0$ and $3x+2y-15z= 8$ is $(-7,-1,-9)$.**

Same question once again [Find the co-ordinates of the point on the join of two points which is nearest to the intersection of two planes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1743441/find-the-co-ordinates-of-the-point-on-the-join-of-two-points-which-is-nearest-to/1743569#1743569)
I have asked this question before,. but want to solve without using vector method.

Attempt:

I have tried to solve it without using vector method.

The 1st straight line joining $(-3, 7, -13)$ and 
$(-6, 1, -10)$ in symmetrical form is $$\frac{x+3}{1}=\frac{y-7}{2}=\frac{z+13}{-1}=r_1 (\text{say})$$ 
Any point on 1st straight line $P(r_1-3, 2r_1+7, -r_1-13)$.

The second straight line in symmetrical form is 
$$\frac{x+\frac{56}{9}}{7}=\frac{y-\frac{40}{3}}{12}=\frac{z-0}{3}=r_2 (\text{say})$$

Any point on 2nd straight line $P(7r_2-\frac{56}{9}, 12r_2+\frac{40}{3}, 3r_2)$.

As P is nearest to the intersection of the planes, consider PQ is the shortest distance(SD) from P on the 2nd straight line. By the definition of  SD, PQ is perpendicular to both the lines written in symmetrical form. The direction cosine of th PQ are $$r_{{1}}-7\,r_{{2}}+{\frac {29}{9}},~~2\,r_{{1}}-12\,r_{{2}}-19/3,~~ -r_{{1}}-3\,r_{{2}}-13$$

As PQ is perpendicular to both the lines, then using the condition of perpendicularity, we have $$3\,r_{{1}}-14\,r_{{2}}+{\frac {16}{9}}=0$$ and $$17\,r_{{1}}-92\,r_{{2}}-{\frac {65}{9}}=0$$. Solving 
$$r_1 = -397/57, r_2 = -467/342$$

Then the coordinate of $P$ is not same than that is asked.

This answer is not same what is expected. Please help me to answer the problem wihout using verctor metheod rather using 3D geometry laws.

Comment: The middle expression in your "direction cosine" should be  $ \ 2r_{{1}}-12\,r_{{2}}-19/3 \ $ .

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Yes. Thanks. I have edited.

Comment: What's the difference between the 3D geometry laws and vector methods ? I reckon 3D geometry laws are derived using vector methods. Or I would rather ask what do you mean by 3D geometry laws?

Comment: @brainst Yes you r right. No difference. Still please help me to solve without using vector knowledge.

Comment: Are you sure there is no typographical error in the equations for the planes?  The point $ \ ( -7, \ -1, \ -9 ) \ $ _is_ on the line between $ \ (-3, \  7, \ -13) \ $ and  $ \ (-6, \ 1, \ -10) \ $ , but while the point is consistent with a solution of $ \ r_1 \ = -4 \ $ , it is _not_ consistent with a single value of $ \ r_2 \ $ .

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Thanks for your reply. I have checked the question once again. There is no typos here. Please suggest me a way out.

Comment: It seems that you are try to solve the problem of nearest points on  two non parallel non intersecting lines. right?

Comment: @Moti I have to find the smallest distance from a point on a straight line to another line.

Comment: I decided to have one last try at this after about five earlier attempts using various methods.  I think there is almost certainly a typo in one (or both?) of the plane equations, because the numbers that emerge in the various simultaneous equations to be solved never lead to parameter values that are integers or ratios of small integers.  So a set of coordinates as simple as $ \ (-7, \ -1, \ -9) \ $ does not emerge, even though that point is definitely on the line segment described.  I don't see a proper resolution to this problem as it stands.